# I'm trying to use data pulled from CoinMarketCap API, I can't access all the information from the dictionary

Tags: django, python-3.x, api

It looks like the information is a List with embedded dictionary. I'm a beginner and don't fully understand how to pull the information from lists/dictionaries.
EXP:

```
'data': [{
     'id': 1,
     'name': 'Bitcoin',
     'symbol': 'BTC',
     'slug': 'bitcoin',
     'num_market_pairs': 7956,
     'date_added': '2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z',
     'tags': ['mineable'],
     'max_supply': 21000000,
     'circulating_supply': 18344737,
     'total_supply': 18344737,
     'platform': None,
     'cmc_rank': 1,
     'last_updated': '2020-04-25T16:09:51.000Z',
     'quote': {
       'USD': {
         'price': 7582.532132,
         'volume_24h': 33998463530.3441,
         'percent_change_1h': -0.102004,
         'percent_change_24h': 0.497048,
         'percent_change_7d': 5.20237,
         'market_cap': 139099557755.5893,
         'last_updated': '2020-04-25T16:09:51.000Z'
       }
     }
   }
```

I can pull the information in 'data', but I can't pull the information in the 'quote':{'USD'} portion of the dictionary.  My code in my template is:

```
 {% for coin_Key in cmc_Data.data %}
        {{ coin_Key }}
        <tr>
        <td>{{ coin_Key.cmc_rank }}</td>
        <td>{{ coin_Key.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ coin_Key.symbol }}</td>
        <td>{{ coin_Key.quote.price }}</td>
        <td>{{ coin_Key.quote.market_cap }}</td>
        <td>{{ coin_Key.total_supply }}</td>
        <td>{{ coin_Key.max_supply }}</td>
        </tr>

  {% endfor %}
```

the {{ coin_Key }} lists all the information, so I know it's pulling from the API properly.

I'm not sure I explained this properly, hit me up with any questions and I'll do my best to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, it looks like you just missed the USD object after quote.

```
{% for coin_Key in cmc_Data.data %}
        {{ coin_Key }}
        <tr>
        <td>{{ coin_Key.cmc_rank }}</td>
        <td>{{ coin_Key.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ coin_Key.symbol }}</td>
        <td>{{ coin_Key.quote.USD.price }}</td>
        <td>{{ coin_Key.quote.USD.market_cap }}</td>
        <td>{{ coin_Key.total_supply }}</td>
        <td>{{ coin_Key.max_supply }}</td>
        </tr>

  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I could have sworn I tried, that, but I've tried so many things, I might have missed that one.  It does work now!  Thanks

Comment: Haha, no worries, we've all been there! :)